# Can't write to shared drive from PHP script (youtube-dl)

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-dl

I have used the search -

I have a shared drive on a windows server
from command prompt I can write on this drive running youtube-dl, however from PHP script- youtube-dl says `permission error ( no permission error on local drive)`

If I run the PHP script that contains youtube-dl from the command prompt as root it works fine.

below is php script

```
echo "Saving $v";
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$v";
$template = '/windowshare/%(id)s.%(ext)s';
$string = ('youtube-dl ' . escapeshellarg($url) . ' -f 22 -o ' .
          escapeshellarg($template));

$descriptorspec = array(
       0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
       1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
       2 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stderr
);
$process = proc_open($string, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
$stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
$stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
fclose($pipes[2]);
$ret = proc_close($process);
echo json_encode(array('status' => $ret, 'errors' => $stderr,
                   'url_orginal'=>$url, 'output' => $stdout,
                   'command' => $string));
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -la /windowshare` when run as root? This sounds like a permission problem.

Comment: hi total 60498714
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root       98304 Dec 14 05:01 .
drwxrwxrwx 10 root root       12288 Dec 18 19:30 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    69870400 Nov 17  2011 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1346825 Oct  8  2007 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    19491952 Oct  8  2007 
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root           0 Apr  7  2014 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     9662390 Nov 23 16:17 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     3972200 Nov 12 15:13

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to php or youtube-dl - the user the webserver is running as simply does not have permissions to write to the destination directory. Either pick another directory or change the permissions. For example, run `sudo chmod a+rw /windowshare` as root to allow everyone to write to the directory.

Comment: thanks i knew that was the problem but was just too confusing to figure it out...

Comment: same message..... works fine from root command "php youtube-dl.php" but not from within httpd pull it over http via browser {"status":1,"errors":"ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 13] Permission denied: